# How to code a search subscription system?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a marketplace website which includes listings of student housing. I would like my users to make a particular search query and then be able to "subscribe" to it, meaning if a new house is listed matching that specific query then they will get an email.

What would be the best way to go about doing something like this? So far I know two options:

- Checking for matched subscriptions when the listing is posted - wouldn't this significantly increase processing time for the user posting the listing if there are thousands of matched subscriptions and it has send thousands of emails?
- Using a CRON job to check all subscriptions against matched listings - I'm guessing this is slightly more tricky

What way would you suggest? I would appreciate some guidance/input.

Comment: You can check when the listing is posted without affecting the user doing the posting as long as you do the check asynchronously, in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked on projects similar to what you are discussing. I've found that it's best to use the CRON approach, and here's why:

You don't want to bombard the user with spam mail several times a day (when a new listing is posted), rather you want to focus on once a day or even once a week, to reduce the chance the user will unsubscribe.

You can schedule the CRON to run the script during 'off-hours' when your system isn't under heavy load as you will need to step through all the users who signed up for your service, then check to see if any new inventory was added that match their search criteria.

Of course this all assumes you have the code/schema in place to facilitate the CRON solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would make some automatic task (e.g. a cronjob) that checks every [day|week|month] for each user which new listings match their preferences. You don't want to to it each time a new listing is posted as this is some drawbacks

1. You need to find the users that are interested in the particular listing, a much more complicated task than the other way around
2. As a user, there's a risk of receiving a lot of e-mails during the day. I think you'd rather have a [daily|weekly|monthly|hourly] digest.